# yarn build:styles error in react while adding tailwind css

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to add tailwind css in my react app created with create react app. There is error in `build:styles` script. Error says like this `postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css` `Error: true is not a PostCSS plugin`. I followed different resources but I am stuck with same error. This is the one article im referring [dev](https://dev.to/hagnerd/setting-up-tailwind-with-create-react-app-4jd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You can try this way, it might be helpful for you.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "npm run build:styles && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "build:styles": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css",
}
```